# PHP: create a list separated by comma

Tags: php

I am trying to create a list of emails separated by coma from a prepared statement.

```
                $prep_stmt = "SELECT m.email
                                FROM roster_par_membre rm
                                LEFT JOIN membre m 
                                        ON m.id_membre = rm.id_membre                           
                                WHERE id_roster = ? 
                                ";
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);           
                if ($stmt) {
                    $stmt->bind_param('i', $roster_id);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->store_result();
                    // get variables from result.
                    $stmt->bind_result($emails_roster);
                    $list = array(); (added)
                    while ($stmt->fetch()){
                        $list[] = $emails_roster;
                    }   
                    $list = implode(',', $list);
```

The output should be a list of emails without separations. 
How can I get a list with coma that I can directly use to send an email to this list? 
At the moment I get a fatal Error: Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings (for the line inside the while!

Comment: I would just store the emails in an array and then `implode(',',$emailArray)` after the loop.

Comment: Use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: Instead of printing the value in the loop, add it into an array.  Then `implode()` that array.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks for the answer. It is what I am trying to do without success

Comment: @Raphael_b: Can you update the question to show that code, what you've tried that isn't working?

Comment: @RocketHazmat just did it

Comment: Why not `select group_concat(',',m.email)`? Less bloating, all the code comes at once and does your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `implode`:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()){
   $emails[] = $emails_roster;
}
$emails = implode(',', $emails);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should be doing something wrong but when I copy your code I get: Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: You've previously assigned a string value to `$emails` then.  Try using `$list` or something else that you haven't already defined.

Comment: Dunno, you're doing something else wrong: http://3v4l.org/H2Hdq You aren't doing `echo $emails[];` are you?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out my exact code:     $prep_stmt = "SELECT m.email
         FROM roster_par_membre rm
         LEFT JOIN membre m 
           ON m.id_membre = rm.id_membre       
         WHERE id_roster = ? 
         ";
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);   
     if ($stmt) {
      $stmt->bind_param('i', $roster_id);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();
      // get variables from result.
      $stmt->bind_result($emails_roster);
      
      while ($stmt->fetch()){
       $list[] = $emails_roster;
      } 
      $list = implode(',', $list);

Comment: OK found the solution; I needed to declare the Array before the while loop $list = array(); Thanks guys @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood it correctly, but if your `$emails_roster` contains an email then simply append to an array:

```
$emails = [];
while ($stmt->fetch()){
 $emails[] = $emails_roster;
}   

print_r($emails); 
echo implode(',', $emails);
```